# How to fetch changed rows by comparing a table with its older version?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, oracle, plsql

I have one log table and one view. 
I would like to fetch the changed rows from the view by comparing it to the log table given an ID_NO.
The ID_NO is fixed between the two tables, whereas other columns can change.

In short, I would like to fetch the rows from Table1 which have one more changed columns in comparison to Table2.

for example:

```
TABLE 1:
ID COL1 COL2 COL3
1  A    B    C
2  34   56   D
3  F    XY   24

TABLE 2:
ID COL1 COL2 COL3
1  A    B    C
2  34   56   F
3  1    XY   24
```

The query should return the following from TABLE2:

```
ID COL1 COL2 COL3
2  34   56   F
3  1    XY   24
```

Please advise.
Many Thanks!

Comment: Please, clarify what do you mean by "one more changed columns"

Comment: What is the structure of the tables in question what changes are you looking for?

Comment: excuse my typo I meant "one OR more changed columns"

Comment: I added a small example above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT  *
FROM    one_view  vw
WHERE   EXISTS
        (
            SELECT  1
            FROM    log_table  t
            WHERE   vw.id_no = t.id_no
        )
;
```

A note after the question was updated:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    table_2  t1
WHERE   EXISTS
        (
            SELECT  1
            FROM    table_1  t2
            WHERE   t1.id_no = t2.id_no
            AND
            (
                    t1.col1 <> t2.col1
                OR  t1.col2 <> t2.col2
                OR  t1.col3 <> t2.col3
            )
        )
;
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have added a small example above. Doesn't your solution fetch all rows from one_view that match the rows from log_table?

Answer (score 0):

you could add a trigger to the changing table that inserts the id in a second table that is used to identify the changed rows from the changing table. Just comparing the values between tables might work but requires a lot of work. Getting the id's of the changed rows might be easier.

Just in case you also want to have the old values, add the changed colums and values to the logging table.